# Insert Mysql data into Json file doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, json, insert

I have a script that doesn't work I hope some developers of you know the solution.

```
<?php
    //Create Database connection
    $db = mysql_connect("localhost","d","d");
    if (!$db) {
        die('Could not connect to db: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    //Select the Database
    mysql_select_db("d",$db);

    //Replace * in the query with the column names.
    $result = mysql_query("select * from events", $db);  

    //Create an array
    $json_response = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        $row_array['id'] = $row['id'];
        $row_array['title'] = $row['title'];
        $row_array['start'] = $row['start'];
        $row_array['end'] = $row['end'];

        //push the values in the array
        array_push($json_response,$row_array);
    }
    echo json_encode($json_response);

    $file = 'events.json';
    // Open the file to get existing content
    $current = file_get_contents($file);
    // Append a new person to the file
    // Write the contents back to the file
    file_put_contents($file, $json_response);
    //Close the database connection

?>
```

But the events.json is empty? Does anyone know the solution?

Comment: Any errors? Also, please do not use the deprecated `mysql_*` API, check out `PDO` or `mysqli` for better database APIs.

Comment: Since this is your first question on SO: this is not a place to have other people debug your code for you. We can answer questions which have a clear, well, *question*. We cannot run this code for you and hence cannot debug it in its entirety. You'll have to go ahead and narrow the problem down yourself to a specific error or line of code, otherwise it's hard to help.

Comment: @Jite No errors.
The script shows the json_encode echo like this

[{"id":"1","title":"Test","start":"2014-09-12T10:30:00-05:00","end":"2014-09-14T10:30:00-05:00"}]

But when I open events.json the file is empty?

Comment: you are not writing the string but the array so it doesn't work

Comment: Sorry @deceze I didn't know that this is the first time I use stackoverflow

Comment: I don't agree, it's often hard to spot your own obvious mistake while others will do it in seconds.

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
$json_response = json_encode($json_response);
```

Comment: This will result in an array to string conversion if you try to write `$final` to a file.

Comment: @Nielsb yes this solution works but I have negative voting. Will you please mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

first,

```
echo json_encode($json_response);
file_put_contents($file, $json_response);
```

this is not writing json you should do this

```
file_put_contents($file, json_encode($json_response));
```

maybe it's the issue, you can't write an array into a file.

second, are you missing some code ?

```
$current = file_get_contents($file);
    // Append a new person to the file
```

we don't see the code to append here, your code just replaces the content by the array $json_response (and not a json encoded array).

Comment: No there is no missing code, I had just used the file_gets_content example from php net

Comment: so I tell you you are missing some code. but your main error is that you don't write the json to the file but the array, so it doesn't work. I wrote you the answer for that.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't stored the json encoded response anywhere. Below your echo statement, add the line:

```
$json_response = json_encode($json_response);
```

Answer (score 0):

You write: `// Append a new person to the file` but never append, rather replaces the content of the file.
When you call `file_put_contents($file, $json_response);` you have not yet made `$json_response` into a json string.

Try change:

```
echo json_encode($json_response);
```

To:

```
$json_response = json_encode($json_response);
```

To correctly convert the data to a json-string.

To append the data to the file (now I'm going to assume that the file contains data formatted the same as the data you are trying to write), load it as you do with `file_get_contents` then  convert the content to an associative array with: `json_decode($dataFromFile, true);` (the `true` flag as second argument makes the return value into an associative array, rather than an object) and merge the two lists, before writing it to file.

Comment: It's really weird he shows the json code nice from the echo. But the data doesn´t show up in the file events.json. The file has 777 permissions

Comment: Yes, cause you are not writing the json string to the file, but the array itself. You never convert it to json, as I wrote in the answer.